# Multiple C++ files in one Visual Studio Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Is it possible to create multiple c++ files and compile them as isolated files in one project in Visual Studio?

For Instance,

Program 1 --> Does Operation 1

Program 2 --> Outputs Hello

Right now, if I create two separate files, it shows the following error

`fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Any workaround for this? Or need to create separate VS projects for the same?

Comment: Are you defining `main` twice?

Comment: _"Is it possible to create multiple c++ files and compile them as isolated files in one project in Visual Studio?"_ No. _"Or need to create separate VS projects for the same?"_ Yes.

Comment: Can I ask why? It's certainly possible, but likely not the best idea.  Why wouldn't you make different projects for each and have them all in the same solution?

Comment: @DeiDei yes, because I am treating them as independent programs

Comment: @RetiredNinja just practising c++, so, wouldn't it be better to have all that code under one project?

Comment: maybe a solution made up of several projects, so you can have as many mains as you want!

Comment: Don't confuse project with solution. The right thing to do is have one project per program, share code where you need/want to (consider building libraries for this), and organize your projects into one or more solutions.

Comment: @RetiredNinja neat and clean answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic definition of a Visual Studio *project* (`.vcxproj` file) is "a collection of source files and settings whose compilation results in one binary (executable or library) file." By definition, if you want two separate executables, you want two separate projects.

Both of these projects can be part of the same Visual Studio *solution* (`.sln` file). Solutions are the things you open in Visual Studio — each running Visual Studio has one solution open (unless it's empty).

If you're familiar with Make, think of a Visual Studio solution as of a `Makefile`, and of Visual Studio projects as of invididual targets in that makefile.

Comment: Yes, I guess I lacked the basic understanding of how Visual Studio works. Thanks!